# Google reCaptcha on Cordova(phonegap)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, recaptcha

I try to use google reCaptcha on my Angular\cordova app, but it's return `"Error: Invalid domain for site key"` when it sends request to recaptcha API. I think this happen because reCaptcha takes value from `window.location.protocol`, which in cordova is `'file://'`

How can I use google reCaptcha for my cordova app? 
Is any way to change `window.location.protocol` before widget sends any request to recaptcha API and restore it after?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, for my Cordova app now i used [ccap](https://github.com/DoubleSpout/ccap)

Comment: As a workaround its possible to use inAppBrowser to display captcha.